# MATLAB 5 .mat file on Octave

Tags: matlab, octave

Can I execute "**Matlab** 5 .mat file on Octave? Let me know please.

Comment: I actually want to execute the instruction.

Comment: I have a .mat file but it can't be opened on octave , it showed loading error.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can run Matlab scripts in Octave in most cases that aren't to complex or rely on Matlab toolkits that haven't been rebuilt for Octave. See Wikipedia's section on Octave's Matlab compatibility:

> Octave has been built with MATLAB compatibility in mind, and shares many features with MATLAB:
>
> 1. Matrices as fundamental data type.
> 2. Built-in support for complex numbers.
> 3. Powerful built-in math functions and extensive function libraries.
> 4. Extensibility in the form of user-defined functions.
>
> In fact, Octave treats incompatibility with MATLAB as a bug; therefore, it can be considered a software clone, […]

Comment: I tried to execute .mat file in Octave but it was failed to load it.

Comment: Could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question about *how* to execute *this particular* program (instead of *if* it's possible *in general*)? The comment section is not suitable or meant for new questions or extended discussion. Thanks.